# Some hints for "If a prime $p = n^2+5$, then $p\equiv 1\mod 10$ or $p\equiv 9\mod 10$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I tried to prove this question by first considering the possible last digit of $p$ when $p=n^2+5$, but that reasoning got me nowhere. Then I tried to prove it by contrapositive, and however I just couldn't really find where to start.
Hence I'm here asking for some hints (only hints, no solution please).

Many thanks,
D.

Comment: Think about $n^2+5\pmod2$ and $n^2+5\pmod5$. I think this will help.

Comment: Well, n = 0 is one exception....

Comment: oh, sorry. Forget to mentioned that in here the $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the notation for modular arithmetic, but is this equivalent to saying $p\equiv\pm1\mod 10$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the last digits of squares, so $n^2$, these are $0,1,4,5,6,9$.

From there you get the last digits of $n^2 +5$.

Now, drop those from the list that cannot be the last digit of a prime.

Comment: Ok, I did tried it with this way as I mentioned. However, I can't prove for that  1 or 9 must work, I did eliminate the rest.

Comment: What do you mean "$1$ or $9$ must work?" It is not true that if $p\equiv 1\pmod{10}$ then $p=n^2+5$. @DeanY

Comment: @DeanY You do not have to prove that "1 or 9 must work". Indeed as said in the comment above it is not even quite clear what that woudl mean;  But there are examples of such primes, that you can exhibit for illustration such as $6^2 + 5 = 41$ is prime and ends in $1$. And you'll also find one that ends in 9.

Comment: Oh, so I did kind of proved it? But I'm a bit confused here. My understanding of the question is that if a prime satisfies that property, then either the last digit must be 1 or 9.

Comment: Good analogy. But if I've given these working examples, I only proved that 1 or 9 may work on some cases since that the rest of the digits are impossible to satisfy the property.

Comment: If there were only $10$ murder suspects, and we have eliminated $8$ of them, we have shown that one of them must have done it. It is unnecessary to show that each of $1$ and $9$ can happen. However, if you want to show that, use $n=6$ and $n=8$.

Comment: @DeanY you are asked to show that every prime of a certain form has last digit 1 or 9. This would true even if there is no such prime at all. Now it happens to be  the case that examples of such primes exists. Yet note that not every number of the form $n^2 +5$ is prime neither is every prime of that form.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your patience. My brain kind of stroke on his question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The possible values of $n^2$ (mod $10$) are $0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9$.  Which ones can you eliminate since $n^2 + 5$ is not prime?

Answer (score 0):

$n^2=0,1, 4,9,6,5$ mod $10$ so $n^2+5= 6,9,4,1,0,5$ mod 10. If $n^2+5$ prime, it is odd and not divisible by 5 the result follows. so you can only have $n=1, 9$ mod 10

Comment: "only hints, no solution please"

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I really did ask for ONLY hint.